# Обособление пояснительных членов предложения

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая после пояснительного члена предложения? Или тире здесь поглощает запятую? (Хотя такого правила я пока не нашла). *Перец овощной, или паприка(,) — слабожгучий вид стручкового перца, получивший особое распространение в венгерской кухне*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном случае запятая после "паприка" закрывает обособленный оборот, а тире стоит между подлежащим и сказуемым. Поглощения нет, так как каждый из знаков ставится по своим условиям.

Правило:
Перед тире по условиям контекста может оказаться запятая. Это возможно, если перед местом постановки тире находится обособленный член предложения или придаточное предложение. В этом случая пишущий ставит два не связанных между собой знака: запятую, закрывающую один оборот, и тире, стоящее между подлежащим и сказуемым. Наиболее распространенной ошибкой пишущих будет непостановка запятой перед тире.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Просто засомневалась, так как не первый раз встречаю отсутствие запятой в подобных предложениях.